# Multiple Card payments - what should I put on the recipt?

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, authorize.net, payment-processing

Our POS software features a multi-credit card payment facility, meaning you can have more than one credit card transaction per purchase. This is not the same as the MasterCard partial authorization facility, but would result in a similar situation.

My question is, if you have taken more than one card payment for the customers purchase, what details should I put on the receipt?

In the case of a single card transaction I am required to show (presumably) the last four digits of the card, the transaction reference number and the transaction authorize code. I also require to put the statement (paraphrased) "I agree to pay the amount in accordance with the card issuer” on the receipt, along with the card holders signature. This is where it gets a bit technical for me, do I need a signature for each card? – and like wise would I require the statement repeated also? Seems a bit much just to repeat it the stuff over and over….

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you need a signature from each cardholder!

Each cardholder needs to get his/her own receipt too; just print multiple receipts.